# Form Border Styles

Tags: vb.net

Wrote the following piece of code to generate a form with a thick border. But the border on my form is too thin (see pic below). Am I making a mistake?...Or is this how a thick border looks like? Can anyone pls help? Also in the code, when I change from FixedDialog to Fixed 3D they imafe of the form is the same -- no change at all!!! This cant be right.

[image: Form]

Code I wrote:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim form1 As New Form()
        form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
        Application.Run(form1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You may be hitting issues with windows visual themes.  If you really want to get funky with visual elements such as boarders, I would turn them off and draw them manually, either using images or paint events

Comment: Windows 10 wants the user's chosen desktop theme to drive UI appearance.  Customization can be done, but it isn't simple.  Most things you'll find around theming are for XP and don't easily translate because Windows 10 themes have different data than XP msstyles.  I tried SkinSoft's visual styler and had DLL related problems.  I also had problems with CodeJock's solution.  For just a border, it may be easiest to use custom paint events.

Comment: P.S. If you set FormBorder to none, the top bar also disappears and you have to implement custom controls for moving, resizing etc.  Custom visual styling in Windows 10 can be a real can of worms, and there don't seem to be any great theming solutions for developers like there used to be for XP.  It can be done, but it isn't going to be simple.

Comment: @Hursey hello. How do I turn off the borders or the visual styling? Do i need to set the border to none ...is that what you are suggesting?